# Building QT 4.7.0 libraries on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: qt, ubuntu, build, qt4

I am trying to build QT 4.7.0 libraries on Ubuntu Linux (Amazon EC2 instance) by following the below steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get build-dep qt4-qmake
sudo ./configure -openssl -release -no-webkit -nomake examples -nomake demos -nomake docs -v -prefix /usr/local/qt4 -opensource
sudo make sub-src
```

Build is failing and I am getting error about qpdf.

```
-I.uic/release-shared -o .obj/release-shared/qpdf.o painting/qpdf.cpp
In file included from ../../include/QtGui/private/qcups_p.h:1:0,
             from painting/qpdf.cpp:47:
../../include/QtGui/private/../../../src/gui/painting/qcups_p.h:78:11: error: âppd_file_tâ does not name a type
../../include/QtGui/private/../../../src/gui/painting/qcups_p.h:80:11: error: âppd_file_tâ does not name a type
../../include/QtGui/private/../../../src/gui/painting/qcups_p.h:81:11: error: âppd_option_tâ does not name a type
../../include/QtGui/private/../../../src/gui/painting/qcups_p.h:84:11: error: âppd_option_tâ does not name a type
../../include/QtGui/private/../../../src/gui/painting/qcups_p.h:87:34: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âtype nameâ with no type [-fpermissive]
../../include/QtGui/private/../../../src/gui/painting/qcups_p.h:87:47: error: template argument 1 is invalid
../../include/QtGui/private/../../../src/gui/painting/qcups_p.h:103:56: error: âppd_group_tâ does not name a type
../../include/QtGui/private/../../../src/gui/painting/qcups_p.h:103:77: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âgroupâ with no type [-fpermissive]
../../include/QtGui/private/../../../src/gui/painting/qcups_p.h:104:62: error: âppd_group_tâ does not name a type
../../include/QtGui/private/../../../src/gui/painting/qcups_p.h:104:75: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âgroupâ with no type [-fpermissive]
../../include/QtGui/private/../../../src/gui/painting/qcups_p.h:108:11: error: âppd_option_tâ does not name a type
../../include/QtGui/private/../../../src/gui/painting/qcups_p.h:110:5: error: âppd_file_tâ does not name a type
painting/qpdf.cpp: In member function âvirtual void QPdfBaseEngine::setProperty(QPrintEngine::PrintEnginePropertyKey, const QVariant&)â:
painting/qpdf.cpp:1470:5: warning: case value â65024â not in enumerated type âQPrintEngine::PrintEnginePropertyKeyâ [-Wswitch]
painting/qpdf.cpp:1464:5: warning: case value â65025â not in enumerated type âQPrintEngine::PrintEnginePropertyKeyâ [-Wswitch]
painting/qpdf.cpp:1467:5: warning: case value â65026â not in enumerated type âQPrintEngine::PrintEnginePropertyKeyâ [-Wswitch]
painting/qpdf.cpp:1473:5: warning: case value â65027â not in enumerated type âQPrintEngine::PrintEnginePropertyKeyâ [-Wswitch]
painting/qpdf.cpp: In member function âvirtual QVariant QPdfBaseEngine::property(QPrintEngine::PrintEnginePropertyKey) constâ:
painting/qpdf.cpp:1584:5: warning: case value â65024â not in enumerated type âQPrintEngine::PrintEnginePropertyKeyâ [-Wswitch]
painting/qpdf.cpp:1578:5: warning: case value â65025â not in enumerated type âQPrintEngine::PrintEnginePropertyKeyâ [-Wswitch]
painting/qpdf.cpp:1581:5: warning: case value â65026â not in enumerated type âQPrintEngine::PrintEnginePropertyKeyâ [-Wswitch]
painting/qpdf.cpp:1587:5: warning: case value â65027â not in enumerated type âQPrintEngine::PrintEnginePropertyKeyâ [-Wswitch]
make[1]: *** [.obj/release-shared/qpdf.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/src/gui'
make: *** [sub-gui-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

However, I was successfully able to make build of QT 4.8.2 by following the same steps.

Comment: please don't paste console output as an image, copy paste the text itself.

Comment: QT successfully build when I removed gui, cups, and phonon support. `sudo ./configure -openssl -release -no-webkit -nomake examples -nomake demos -nomake docs -v -prefix /usr/local/qt4 -opensource -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-gui -no-cups`